# Display row data in new columns (pivot?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm currently working with a very simple query that pulls a list of people who visited a certain location within the past 3 years. My issue is that there are a number of people who have visited multiple times during that 3-year time period, so those people have multiple rows attributed to them. What I'd like to do is take a field such as their visit date and display it in a column instead, adding columns for each additional visit date so all of a given person's data is displayed on a single row. Upon doing some investigating, it sounds like a pivot function is sort of what I'm looking for, but I'm having some trouble figuring out how to apply it to my specific situation.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
d.PersonID,
d.DOB,
d.Age as [Current Age],
DATEDIFF(YY,d.DOB,v.VisitDate) -                                        
   CASE                                                                                             
       WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YY,d.DOB,v.VisitDate),d.DOB)   
       > v.VisitDate THEN 1                                                                         
    ELSE 0                                                                                          
   END AS [Age at Visit],
v.VisitDate

FROM Demographic d JOIN Visit v ON d.PersonID = v.PersonID

WHERE VisitDate BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND '12/31/2020'
```

So of course with the way this is currently written, I end up with results like this, with multiple rows for each visitor:

```
PersonID    ...    VisitDate
---------------------------------
1001        ...    04/06/2018
1001        ...    10/19/2019
1002        ...    07/20/2019
1003        ...    11/17/2017
1003        ...    02/01/2019
1003        ...    08/11/2020
```

And this is what I'd like it to look like. I realize this doesn't account for my age-at-visit calculation, but I might go ahead and get rid of that if it means making this work:

```
PersonID    ...    VisitDate1    VisitDate2    VisitDate3
------------------------------------------------------------
1001        ...    04/06/2018    10/19/2019
1002        ...    07/20/2019
1003        ...    11/17/2017    02/01/2019    08/11/2020
```

Given what I know about this data, any given person *should* only have a maximum of 4 visits during this timeframe, but is there a way to automatically add extra columns just in case someone has more than 4?

Comment: Is the max of visits 3 per person ?

Comment: The max per person *should* only be 4 (potentially one in 2017, 2018, 2019, and 2020) but there may be a few anomalies

Comment: there may be a few anomlies = dynamic pivot

Answer (score 0):

See if below works for you... adding more the 4 visits dynamically can be achieved by using dynamic sql

```
CREATE TABLE #T (
ID int,
Visit Date
)
GO


INSERT #T
SELECT 1001, '04/06/2018' UNION
SELECT 1001, '10/19/2019' UNION
SELECT 1002, '07/20/2019' UNION
SELECT 1003, '11/17/2017' UNION
SELECT 1003, '02/01/2019' UNION
SELECT 1003, '08/11/2020' 
GO

SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT * 
        , CONCAT('Visit', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Visit)) AS Visit_Cnt
    FROM #T
) X
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Visit) FOR Visit_Cnt IN([Visit1], [Visit2], [Visit3], [Visit4])
) A
```